# Change the index of place, according to the created method (RUBY challenge)

Tags: ruby, swap

My question is:

```
array = [0, 1]
```

and the mandatory instruction of the challenge is to use "instr" to change the index positions:

```
instr = "0 <> 1"
```

From that, I have to swap the index places, according to "instr", as a method.
The question is, how?

Comment: I can't make much sense out of your `instr = "0 <> 1"`. Are you saying that you need to make a method called `instr` that swaps positions of a passed-in array?

Comment: instr is like a "parameter", which inside the function will get the indexes that will be exchanged;

For example:

array = [a, ab, ac]
instr = "0<>2"

That is, from this I know that my return should be:

array = [ac, ab, a]

That is, instr will always indicate which indexes I should change in the array.

So, I have several arrays where these instructions called instr are telling me which indexes should be exchanged within the arrays.

But I don't know how to make this string that will be called by instr will be able to make these exchanges.

Comment: Is `instr` always two indices separated by `<>`?

Comment: Yes, but the numbers change.

Answer (score 1):

You need to extract the indexes from the `instr` first and assign them to a variable (`swap` in my example). Then you can swap the values at the indexes in a one-liner.

```
array = [:a, :b, :c, :d]
instr = "0 <> 2"

i, j = instr.split("<>").map(&:to_i) #=> [0, 2]
array[i], array[j] = array[j], array[i]

puts array
#=> [:c, :b, :a, :d]
```

Comment: `i, j = instr.split("<>").map(&:to_i)` would result in less typing afterwards

Comment: @Stefan That's a good idea. I updated my answer.

Comment: Seize the moment, do you guys recommend any good Ruby courses? Complete course. Is there any free?

Comment: @Edd I wouldn't recommend a free course, personally, just because spending a little money is a great personal motivator. [Launch School](https://launchschool.com/) will give you the opportunity to learn Ruby to the expert level. There's a free portion at the beginning to see whether it's really something you are interested in. After that, it's $199 a month. It's where I learned Ruby, and I can say I know Ruby very well.